# The issue is,it takes 3 seconds.I want to check foreground app every 1000milliseconds#THANKS_IN_ADVANCE

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

```
UsageEvents usageEvent = mUsageStatsManager.queryEvents(time - 100 * 1000, time);
UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
// get last event
while (usageEvent.hasNextEvent()) {
  usageEvent.getNextEvent(event);
}
if (topPackageName.equals(event.getPackageName()) && event.getEventType() ==
    UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
  pActivity = topPackageName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the `queryStats` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#queryEvents(long,%20long)):

> NOTE: The last few minutes of the event log will be truncated to prevent abuse by applications.

So this is working as intended.

Comment: The weird thing is this is actually working in real-time for me from Android 5.0 through 9.0. There's no noticeable truncation/lag at all.